# laravel 5 - Eloquent relations

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table a migration called **plates**.

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->integer('supplier_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('supplier_id')->references('id')->on('suppliers')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
```

And a model called **Plates**

```
 public function supplier()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Suppliers','supplier_id');
}
```

And a model **Suppliers** model

```
 public function plates()
        {
            return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Plates');
        }
```

when I check the relations with in the route doing this kind of thing.

```
 $storage = Suppliers::find(1);
   $att = $storage->plates;

   dd($att);
```

it just does not work. But the other way around works just fine.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have checked the docs and did countless other tries, but I can't understand it anymore.

Here is the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Tvlq.png) which keeps poping up.

Comment: return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Plates', 'supplier_id');

Comment: @Daan Well,  that worked! Thanks a lot. But I was curios why this happens. Is there something wrong with my naming conventions? Am I doing things the wrong way?

Comment: Your model is called `Suppliers` so it automatically thinks your foreign key is called suppliers_id unless you specify otherwise.

Comment: I suggest you name your models with a singular noun: it will save you a lot of headaches now and in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You must add the parameter in the plates function at Supplier Model, you created the model in plural, Suppliers, so it tries to find a key suppliers_id

```
  public function plates()
  {
      return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Plates', 'supplier_id');
  }
```